# API Response received many times

Tags: java, android

I have RecyclerView that contain list of movies that received from some API.

This API contains pages and each page contain 20 items.

I can't use paging library now , so I need to load items in different way.

That what I do :

Each time user reaches last item in RecyclerView, I call request with next page .

Then adding the response to the current list (Precious page) and setting notifyDataSetChanged.

```
mRVMovies.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Loading next page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mMoviesViewModel.getAllMovies(nextPage).observe(MoviesListFragment.this, new Observer<List<MovieResult>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(List<MovieResult> movieResults) {
                            mMovieResultArrayList.addAll(movieResults);
                            mMoviesRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            Log.d("myDebug", "onChanged: "+movieResults.size());
                            nextPage++;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

The problem is, that on each scroll , moviesArrayList is multiplying by it self.

On first scroll i receive 20 items- Normal behaviour.
On second scroll i received 60 items - BAD behaviour.

getAllMoviesFunction from viewmodel.

```
public MutableLiveData<List<MovieResult>> getAllMovies(int page){
        return mRepository.getAllMoviesMutableLiveData(page);
    }
```

getMovies from repository:

```
public MutableLiveData<List<MovieResult>> getAllMoviesMutableLiveData(int page) {
        AppService appService = RetrofitInstance.getService();
        disposable = appService.getAllMovies(mApplication.getResources().getString(R.string.api_key),
                mApplication.getResources().getString(R.string.language),
                mApplication.getString(R.string.popularity_desc),page)
                .retryWhen(throwable ->
                        throwable.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<MoviesResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(MoviesResponse moviesResponse) {
                        mAllMoviesMutableLiveData.setValue(moviesResponse.getMovieResults());
                        disposable.dispose();
                    }
                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable throwable) {
                        disposable.dispose();
                    }
                });
        return mAllMoviesMutableLiveData;
    }
```

And api services:

```
@GET("3/discover/movie")
    Observable<MoviesResponse> getAllMovies(
            @Query("api_key") String api_key,
            @Query("language") String language,
            @Query("sort_by") String sort_by,
            @Query("page") int page
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your API call from `onScrollChanged` method and add into `onScrolled` method.

like this

```
 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();

                if (!isLoading) {
                    if (linearLayoutManager != null && linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == rowsArrayList.size() - 1) {
                        //bottom of list!
                        loadMore();// you can call API here to fetch data
                        isLoading = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Fo reference see the demo code [Recyclerview load more item](https://www.journaldev.com/24041/android-recyclerview-load-more-endless-scrolling)

Comment: Hi mdroid, I tried your answer, but still get same behaviour.

Comment: Have you tried the demo code that I have shared in answer? let me share your code from the GitHub link if possible.

Answer (score 0):

here is the way how I fixed it:

```
private boolean canLoadMore = false;

mRVMovies.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                    canLoadMore = true;
                    currentPage++;
                    mMoviesViewModel.getAllMovies(currentPage, genreID).observe(MoviesListFragment.this, new Observer<List<MovieResult>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(List<MovieResult> movieResults) {
                            if (canLoadMore) {
                                mMovieResultArrayList.addAll(movieResults);
                                mMoviesRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                canLoadMore = false;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } 
            }
        });
```